# Thymeleaf Spring MVC exception when model object equals overriden

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I get a error when I override equals method of my Model class named Attribute. The error is following:

> 2016-08-05 16:28:38.945[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m2434[0;39m
>   [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8079-exec-5][0;39m
>   [36morg.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine            [0;39m [2m:[0;39m
>   [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8079-exec-5] **Exception processing template
>   "/attribute-value-new": Error during execution of processor
>   'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringOptionFieldAttrProcessor'**
>   (/attribute-value-new:96) [2m2016-08-05 16:28:38.953[0;39m
>   [31mERROR[0;39m [35m2434[0;39m [2m---[0;39m
>   [2m[nio-8079-exec-5][0;39m
>   [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m
>   **> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during
>   execution of processor**
>   'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringOptionFieldAttrProcessor'
>   (/attribute-value-new:96)] with root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   my.com.core.model.Attribute   at
>   my.com.core.model.Attribute.equals(Attribute.java:119) ~[classes/:na]
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeEquals(ObjectUtils.java:297)
>   ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectedValueComparator.isSelected(SelectedValueComparator.java:75)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectedValueComparatorWrapper.isSelected(SelectedValueComparatorWrapper.java:34)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringOptionFieldAttrProcessor.doProcess(SpringOptionFieldAttrProcessor.java:69)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.java:103)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695

This equals method is overriden is:

```
  @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return ((Attribute)obj).getId()==this.id;
        }
```

Thymeleaf call:

```
    <div th:if="${account!= null}" id="attribute-value-attribute">
<select th:field="*{attribute}" class="form-control">
<option th:each="attribute : ${account.attributes}"
th:value="${{attribute}}" th:text="${attribute.name}" />
</select>
</div>
```

If I remove the overridden equals method the error is resolved. It seems Thymeleaf is unable to work with overridden equals.

Comment: stacktrace clearly shows you are getting a classCastException from String to Attribute

Comment: Yes but it shows because Thymeleaf is converting {{attribute}} to a string and then trying to call equals on this string. It is not picking up the corresponding object. I don't know how thymeleaf internally works but this would mean i cannot override my equals method if i have to use them with thymeleaf.

Comment: try something like - if(obj instanceof Attribute) <typecast and compare id>  else return false